# Oracle Apex - Load files into the Static Files folder via front-end page

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a page where the user is able to see and select images that have been previously loaded into the Static Application Files folder.
The end result is something like this (on a PL/SQL Dynamic region):

```
DECLARE

CURSOR C_OPPTYS IS
select distinct
FILE_NAME
from apex_application_static_files
where APPLICATION_ID = 99999;

BEGIN

For C1 in Images loop

HTP.P('
<div style="height: 200px; width: 230px%;">

    <img style="background: url(#APP_FILES#'|| C1.FILE_NAME ||'); width:100%; height:100%; 
object-fit: cover;  display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">

</div>
</div>');

END LOOP;
    
END;
```

I'm using that to set the user-selected image on page, but not sure how can I create a front-end option for the user to load the images themselves into the Static folder. Any ideas?
(as a plan B I'm thinking on having a table with a BLOB to load the files but! how can I set the CSS using a file stored in a regular table? Current Static CSS path would be #APP_FILES#filename, with a BLOB file I'm not sure how would that look.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to upload images to `#APP_FILES#`, but - if you have them in a `BLOB` column, here's a sample function which returns `HTML` table that contains 4 images in a row, and as many rows as needed. See if it helps.

Basically, you'd use that function in (classic?) report's source query.

```
FUNCTION f_album
   RETURN CLOB
IS
   i        NUMBER := 0;                                     -- counter (number of images)
   l_str    VARCHAR2 (1000);                                    -- one table cell contents
   l_photo  VARCHAR2 (200);                                                -- image itself
   l_spr    NUMBER := 4;        -- number of images in a table row (4 images in this case)
   retval   CLOB;
BEGIN
   FOR cur_r IN (SELECT o.empno
                   FROM employees o
                  WHERE NVL (DBMS_LOB.getlength (o.photo), 0) > 0)
   LOOP
      i := i + 1;

      -- function returns images
      l_photo := APEX_UTIL.get_blob_file_src ('P3_PHOTO', cur_r.empno);

      l_str :=
            CASE WHEN MOD (i + l_spr - 1, l_spr) = 0 THEN '<tr>' END
         || '<td style="vertical-align:top">'
         || '<img src="'
         || l_photo
         || '" width="150"/>'
         || '</td>'
         || CASE WHEN MOD (i, l_spr) = 0 THEN '</tr>' END;

      retval := retval || l_str;
   END LOOP;

   retval := '<table style="width:100%">' || retval || '</tr> </table>';

   RETURN retval;
END f_album;
```